# Linux machine is not detecting network card

Tags: networking

I have a machine with CentOS 6.5 installed. The machine works fine everyday, but sometimes when I reboot the machine, then the NIC doesn't detect. When I use the command `ifup eth2` then it shows the error message "device not present".
But, when I poweroff the machine completely and then start it again, then it start working fine. Now the cards start detecting. What is problem in this case?

Comment: How is the NIC connected? Have you examined kernel boot logs, and compared a working boot to a non-working one? Also, have you confirmed with `lspci`/`lsusb`/etc. that NIC didn't detect (and not that, for example, somehow just got a different name).

Comment: No i havnt , i am a new user, i dont know how to check the kernal log

Answer (score 0):

There might be other causes, but I have seen this happen with older network cards that did get firmware uploaded by there driver. RDuring reboot (without complete poweroff) the card would not be completely reinitialised and could never be restart into (dual boot) Windows and would fail some of the time is rebooted into Linux.
With that system I just got used to briefly powering it off briefly.

Comment: can u please tell me any other solution as this is at remote location.